# From where I should start to study cryptography?

Tags: encryption, decryption-oracle

I am preparing for an exam which include cryptography challenges. I got five months to study. But I don't know from where I should start to study cryptography. Please help me. If possible, please describe website names and book titles which are suitable for beginners.

Comment: Katz and Lindell's book is often recommended https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html